# Play video on screen in full screen mode in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play video in full screen mode when screen is just launched but some how i am not able to play the video.I am using below code to play the video but video is not playing please tell me how can i play it in full screen mode.

```
  NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:self.image_url]];
            [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
            CGRect movieFrame;
            movieFrame.size = self.view_video.frame.size;
            [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:movieFrame];
            [self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
            [self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            [self.moviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];

            [self.view_video addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
            [self.view_video bringSubviewToFront:self.moviePlayerController.view];
            [self.moviePlayerController play];
            [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:TRUE animated:TRUE];
            [self.moviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
            [self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (movieExists)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    player.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

        [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];  

        [self.moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:NO];

        [self.moviePlayerController setContentURL:self.videoURL];

        [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; 

        self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

        [self.moviePlayerController play];

        [self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];
```